How to identify audio and video AVCaptureDevices that are from the same hardware?
I'm working on a macOS application that captures audio and video. When the user selects a video capture source (most likely an elgato box), I would like the application to automatically select the audio input from the same device. I was achieving this by pairing video and audio sources that had the same name, but this doesn't work when the user plugs in two capture devices of the same make and model.
With the command system_profiler SPUSBDataType I can list all the USB devices, and I can see that the two elgato boxes have different serial numbers. If I could find this serial number, then I could figure out which AVCaptureDevices come from the same hardware.
Is there a way to get the manufacturer's serial number from the AVCaptureDevice object? Or a way to identify the USB device for an AVCaptureDevice, and from there I could get the serial or some other unique ID?

With a little poking you can figure out what you want from the AVCaptureDevice uniqueID and transportType fields. It's not exactly documented, but it saves you a trip into IOKit & probably will never change anyway.

Thanks for your comment @GordonChilds. I've looked at the uniqueIDs, and I don't believe the information I need is there. E.g. the ID for the audio device is AppleUSBAudioEngine:Elgato:Elgato 4K X:A7SNB3481461RU:3 (note the serial number is actually in there), while the ID for the video device on the same box is 0x12000000fd9009c. I'm not sure how to correlate these when there are multiple identical boxes. I'm curious about this "trip into IOKit". Do you see a way I can find out if 2 capture devices are on the same hardware?

0x1200000 is the location ID, so you could find that looking in the IOKit registry, get the USB serial number then check the usb audio device uniqueIDs to see which of them match, but that's just for USB.
